# How to implement conditional logic in ansible regarding modified files?

Tags: ansible

In ansible, I want to restart a service only if the configuration was changed.

Here is an example:

```
- hosts: workers
  tasks:
  - lineinfile: 'dest=/etc/default/autofs regexp=^OPTIONS= line="OPTIONS=\"-O soft\"" backup=yes'
  - shell: service autofs reload
```

As you can see this code will always restart the `autofs`, even when the configuration file is not updated.

How can I improve this so it will restart only when the configuration file is changed?

Note: that's a generic question that is not specific to autofs, it could apply to any service where I do want to execute something IF a configuration file was changed, probably via `lineinfile` or `ini_file` core modules.

Answer (score 3):

For a start you should be using the [service module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html) for controlling running services when running out. In general, if there's a proper module for something and it does what you need then you should do that and only resort to shelling out for edge cases.

Also, when an Ansible task runs it [returns a series of facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/common_return_values.html) that you can register to be able to use directly. This nearly always includes a `changed` attribute which is a boolean saying whether Ansible thinks it changed something (it can't always know. If a `shell` task returns something in stdout then it assumes something changed unless you directly override it with [`changed_when`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result)).

So you could go with something like this:

```
- hosts: workers
  tasks:
  - name: Set autofs options
    lineinfile: 'dest=/etc/default/autofs regexp=^OPTIONS= line="OPTIONS=\"-O soft\"" backup=yes'
    register: result

  - name: reload autofs is autofs options are changed
    service: name=autofs state=reloaded
    when: result.changed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would create a role instead of using loose tasks right in your playbook you could work with [handlers](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change). Also see [Best practices: Task And Handler Organization For A Role](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#task-and-handler-organization-for-a-role).

Tasks file of your role:

```
- name: Change autofs config
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/default/autofs
              regexp=^OPTIONS=
              line="OPTIONS=\"-O soft\""
              backup=yes
  notify:
    - Restart autfs
```

Then in your handlers file of the same role:

```
- name: Restart autfs
  service: name=autfs
           state=restarted
```

The handler gets notified whenever the config tasks has a changed state.

PS: I used the [service module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html) for managing the service. You should only use the shell module if no specific module for your tasks is available

[Regarding roles:](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization)

> One thing you will definitely want to do though, is use the “roles” organization feature, which is documented as part of the main playbooks page. See [Playbook Roles and Include Statements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html). You absolutely should be using roles. Roles are great. Use roles. Roles! Did we say that enough? Roles are great.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I landed on this and felt there was more to add to what others have already answered. You should probably use a handler, but you do not need to do a discreet role to use a handler. Here's an example of handlers used directly in the playbook.

```
---
- hosts: workers
  tasks:
    - lineinfile: 'dest=/etc/default/autofs regexp=^OPTIONS= line="OPTIONS=\"-O soft\"" backup=yes'
      notify: reload autofs
  handlers:
    - name: reload autofs
      service: name=autofs state=reloaded
```

One thing to note.. handlers fire off at the end of the play. So if you have multiple tasks, and you're expecting the handler to fire after the task that notified it, you might be in for a bad time. You can do a 'meta' task to flush_handlers if you need that handler to fire off in a sequential order with your tasks, or you can go the register/conditional way like ydaetskcoR provided. In your play, with a single task, it doesn't really matter.